# ENS subdomain character limits

Tags: ens

Can anyone advise the character limits on ens sub domains? I a looking to know a min and max character limit (ens .eth addresses for example have to be at least 3 characters).

Am I able to have 1.domain.eth where I own domain.eth for example?

I've searched and am unable to find an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no character limit for creating subdomains.

To create a new 'domain.eth' you must interact with `ETHRegistrarController.sol`, [which has a check for valid names](https://github.com/ensdomains/ens-contracts/blob/master/contracts/ethregistrar/ETHRegistrarController.sol#L77-L79).

To create a new subdomain ("subnode"), you interact with a different contract, `ENSRegistry.sol`, which doesn't have any check ([indeed you can pass directly the hash](https://github.com/ensdomains/ens-contracts/blob/master/contracts/registry/ENSRegistry.sol#L57)).

This is an example of 2 characters subdomain: [me.etherbase.eth](https://app.ens.domains/name/me.etherbase.eth/details).

Comment: Thanks so much thats perfect. I'll upvote the answer once i hit the required 15 rep :)